# UIImageJPEGRepresentation & UIImagePNGRepresentation slow performance

Tags: image, performance, nsdata

I ran some tests on both UIImageJPEGRepresentation & UIImagePNGRepresentation. Those times were on the same image:

```
 1. It takes 130ms for the JPEG
 2. It takes 271ms for the PNG.a
```

When I ran both methods after each other it took

```
 3. 273ms for the PNG and then 49ms for JPEG
```

and the other way around it took

```
 4. 104ms for the JPEG and 177ms for the PNG
```

The second call takes less time!

My problem is that I need to save entries to core data but I have multiple images so it can take quite a lot of time to save all the images.

Are there any faster ways to convert images to NSData?